# getelementsbyname addeventlistener

Tags: javascript, html, dom

```
<form>
<a name='lala'/><a name='lala'/>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var elem=document.getElementsByName('lala');
alert(elem.length);
</script>
```

alert pops up 0!??
so that makes it next one not working!??

```
for(i in elem)
 elem[i].addEventListener('click',function(){alert('lala');}, false);
```

many thanks!!

Comment: Which browser? Works for me in Chrome 10: http://jsfiddle.net/cCqFD/ IE seems to be behave a bit differently, but it should work too: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125 | Apart from that: Why add a click event listener to an element, that cannot be seen anyway?

Comment: The problem might be some browsers don't like `<a name="lala"/>`. Even though this is valid xml, i don't think it is actually valid html.

Comment: @Felix but why does it pops up more than 2? check this one please: [link](jsfiddle.net/Np5zg/) it pops up 4? ;)

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: `<a>` are not self-closing, they need a closing tag. That confuses the parser and at least Chrome tries to correct this and produces the following DOM `<div id="form"><form><label><a name="urlgal"></a><a name="urlgal"></a></label><a name="urlgal"></a></form></div><a name="urlgal"></a>` (there are four `a` elements now). It works if you close the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/Np5zg/1/

Comment: that is very odd cause i made it work on the 'actual' web page. please check it [HERE](http://lookaroundyou.net/login/insert.php) js code is included at the bottom of the page, and that apparently was problem, cause it used to be in the head before.

Comment: @daniel.tosaba: Oh yeah I could have told you that ;) But in your example, your script came after the HTML code so this did not seem to be a problem. The explanation is simple: If you put the code in the head, it is executed before the remaining HTML is parsed, hence the elements you are looking for don't exist yet. You should add this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is not working because by the time you call `document.getElementsByName`
the DOM elements are not loaded yet, therefore, your `document.getElementsByName('lala');` will return null.

There are several ways to perform a function just when the DOM elements are ready. The simplest way is to create a function  in your `<head>` and call it in the load event of your body

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function domLoaded() {
       var elem=document.getElementsByName('lala');
          alert(elem.length);
       }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="domLoaded();">


   ....


</body>
```

When you placed the javascript function in the end of your   tag, you just began to call the code when your elements where ready. That will work too, but isn't it better to do things the right way and place all your JS code in the head element? By throwing JS code all over the code is going to make you life hell when you need to fix things.

Answer (score 0):

getElementsByName is not supported by all browsers, see [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html) for all browser compatibilities.

It works for me, however. I am running Chrome 10.0.648.127

Comment: Actually it is supported by all browsers (based on this) but the implementations behave differently.

Answer (score -3):

javascript code had to be included at the bottom of the page,
so that's why folks you should always put your js code to the bottom of the page.
many thanks to everybody ;)

Comment: But in your question the Javascript code _is_ included at the bottom.